# how to disable sorting on a particular row in ExtJS

Tags: sorting, extjs, extjs4.1

I have an ExtJs grid, in which I dont want to sort first row. How to neglect that with ExtJS sorters?

```
sortchange( ct, column, direction, eOpts ){
      console.log(column, ct);
    },
```

Can we do with `sortchange` listener ?

Answer (score 2):

In ExtJs docs provide method to disable sort column using **sortable** have method to load data. [You can refer ExtJs docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-sortable)

I have create small demo to show you, how it work. [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26n2)

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'employeeStore',
    fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'dep', 'hired'],
    data: [{
        firstname: "Michael",
        lastname: "Scott",
        seniority: 7,
        dep: "Management",
        hired: "01/10/2004"
    }, {
        firstname: "Dwight",
        lastname: "Schrute",
        seniority: 2,
        dep: "Sales",
        hired: "04/01/2004"
    }, {
        firstname: "Jim",
        lastname: "Halpert",
        seniority: 3,
        dep: "Sales",
        hired: "02/22/2006"
    }, {
        firstname: "Kevin",
        lastname: "Malone",
        seniority: 4,
        dep: "Accounting",
        hired: "06/10/2007"
    }, {
        firstname: "Angela",
        lastname: "Martin",
        seniority: 5,
        dep: "Accounting",
        hired: "10/21/2008"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Demo',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'firstname',
        sortable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Last Name',
        dataIndex: 'lastname'
    }, {
        text: 'Hired Month',
        dataIndex: 'hired',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'M',
        sortable: false
    }, {
        text: 'Department (Yrs)',
        xtype: 'templatecolumn',
        tpl: '{dep} ({seniority})'
    }],
    width: 400,
    forceFit: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is write special sorters to keep the first row always first. An example of a custom sorter function can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016618/grouping-in-store-with-values-in-extjs-6-2/44017477#44017477).

In your case, you could use a special boolean field "keepOnTop" and the sorter:

```
sorterFn: function(a, b) {
    // Special sorting for first line:
    if(a.get('keepOnTop')) return 1;
    if(b.get('keepOnTop')) return -1;
    // Usual sorting; example with "department" index:
    if(a.get('department') < b.get('department')) return 1;
    if(a.get('department') > b.get('department')) return -1;
    return 0;
},
```

(Please be aware that this sorter expects only a single line to have keepOnTop set to true.)

Comment: ` var CiGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
   
    store: mystore,
 border: false,
    **columns: datastore.columns,**  `

I have grid and columns like this in my application, how to accomodate sorterFn in this ?

Comment: [In 6.2.1 this is easy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-sorter), in 4.1.3 not so much. It seems you have to override the [doSort](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/source/Column3.html#Ext-grid-column-Column-method-doSort) function of the columns.

Comment: How to do that, if you can clarify more on that.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, 
What will be the logic to have sort on other columns as it was earlier. Do I need to write logic for column value which is called for sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

check this
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-sortable

here a example...

```js
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Nombre',  dataIndex: 'name', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```